# C++ How to avoid dynamic_casting?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have done a little research on dynamic_casting, and I read that it creates something called the RTTI,
which is loaded in RAM too at start-up. At some platforms this isn't supported too I think. So I was wondering if there was any good solution to avoid it.

Let's say I have Statement class

```
class Statement
{
    std::list<Operand*> operands;
};
```

and a Operand is a class with more subclasses like, memory address, register, ect. ( For some wondering, I am trying to make an assembler.:P

I can't go downcasting with dynamic_cast, which is also bad if I could. But what if I added a enumeration to Operand, which defines it's Type, so I can downcast with static_cast by using it's type.

I could make it a const, and define it in the constructor of every subclass right?

I am looking forward to what you all think.

Christian

Comment: Ideally you'd just rely on polymorphism, and not care about the concrete type of the object at all. Why do think you need downcasting?

Comment: On which platform should the assembler run ? If it should run on a developer's computer, then it's safe to assume that RTTI's effect will be neglectible. If it should run on an embedded target with (very) low spec, then you are on the right path. Now I feel like you are using dynamic_cast wrongly. For your common OOP tasks, it should not be necessary to dynamic_cast, just use the methods defined in the base class.

Comment: I agree with @BjörnPollex . If your problem cannot be solved w/o type casting, the class design is probably wrong. But if you don't care, I suggest you to engage the visitor pattern. But pay attention, this pattern provides the same functionality as enumeration and generally leads to the component coopling

Comment: Also `boost::variant` is an option here.

Answer (score 2):

Making a type - is an option.

But consider making a generic `interface` for `Operand`. So your `memory address`, `register`, ect will inplement that interface and you will be able to treat them polymorphic.

In case you can't invent such `interface` - consider redesigning your classes because it looks like they don't need to have a common interface.

If you need code reuse - go with `composition`, not `inheritance`

Answer (score 2):

If you decide you want to down cast, you may consider using an interface to get to the appropriate type. But, you could also list out the subclasses explicitly as well.

```
class Operand {
public:
    enum Type { OT_Address, OT_Register, /*...*/ };
    virtual Type type () const = 0;
    virtual AddressOperand * isAddress () { return 0; }
    virtual RegisterOperand * isRegister () { return 0; }
    //...
};
```

Then, instead of a down cast, you would simply invoke the method associated with the type. The derived class would implement it:

```
class AddressOperand : public Operand {
public:
    Operand::Type type () const { return Operand::OT_Address; }
    AddressOperand * isAddress () { return this; }
    //...
};
```